# Remove duplicates from a csv

Tags: python, csv

Ok so I have a csv file, and I want to remove duplicates. I have a working code example, but I am also later trying to copy it, the copy is showing up blank, I believe because the code I am using to remove duplicates is not closing the csv file to then be copied. If I were to copy the file before removing the duplicates it works perfectly. But I want to avoid removing duplicates on both files.

Working code to remove duplicates:

```
rows = csv.reader(open('scan.csv', 'r', newline=''))
newrows = []
for row in rows:
    if row not in newrows:
        newrows.append(row)
writer = csv.writer(open('scan.csv', 'w', newline=''))
writer.writerows(newrows)
```

I believe the answer for python3 is to instead of doing the above code, to use a with statement. But I am totally lost on how to convert that code into a with statement. Heres what I am trying (which is probably completely wrong)

```
with open('scan.csv', 'r', newline='') as rows:
for row in rows:
    if row not in newrows:
        newrows.append(row)
with open('scan.csv', 'w', newline='') as writer:
writer.writerows(newrows)
```

In case I am wrong about the entire base issue, I am doing this to copy.

```
shutil.copyfile('scan.csv', 'iplist.csv')
```

running this before my working code, works fine. Running this after the working code, makes an empty csv file.

Im also trying to build this whole thing without importing anything that has to be installed on windows like panda.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Using a With Statement to remove duplicates from a csv

Pattern using nested `with ...`

---

**Reference**: Buil-in Functions

- [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

  > Typical uses of context managers include, closing opened files
- [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

  > A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
- [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash)

  > Return the hash value of the object

---

```
_set = set()

with open('scan.csv', 'r', newline='') as in_file, \
     open('iplist.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:

    for line in in_file:
        _hash = hash(line)
        if _hash not in _set:
            out_file.write(line)
            _set.add(_hash)
```

Comment: or https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: @cricket_007: The OP stated: **NO PANDAS**.